# Facebook API Request limitations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got only one user which is the app itself connecting to Graph API and as it's said in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting
i should be limited to 200calls an hour.
It's been a week i'm making 720 request per hour without being restricted soo i'm kinda confused.
Is the API request limit not exact ?

Comment: It likely isn’t “exact”, no. Making it _exact_ would probably consume more resources - and a measure that is supposed to improve overall platform performance should perhaps rather not be doing that. Plus, for such “small” apps, it is likely enforced less strict. Whether your tiny app makes four times the amount of “allowed” calls here is likely not going to affect the platform much; for an app with user numbers in the 10k or 100k and more, that’s a different thing.

Comment: But actually i want to upgrade my app to a call by second, is there any way to be sure i wont be restricted ?

Comment: When the response headers the documentation mentions start appearing, then you know that you need to do something.

Comment: In fact i wonder if there is a limitation for an api GET